# Let $G$ be a simple graph with minimum vertex degree $\delta$. Does $G$ contain a subdivision of the complete graph on $\delta+1$ vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

Every simple graph I construct with minimum vertex degree $\delta$ contains a subdivision of $K_{\delta+1}$. I am wondering if this holds in general. If it does, I would love a proof; if it doesn't, I would really appreciate a counterexample.

Comment: For those who like easy counterexamples, the Petersen graph is not one. I will investigate further.

Comment: What types of examples have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the complete bipartite graph $K_{4,4}$, in which you're hoping to find a subdivision of $K_5$.

The problem is that $K_5$ has $10$ edges, so a subdivision of $K_5$ has $10$ paths between its degree-$4$ vertices. At most $6$ of those paths can be single edges of $K_{4,4}$, because the largest $5$-vertex bipartite graph has only $6$ edges. The remaining $4$ paths must each have an interior vertex, but that brings us up to $9$ vertices total. $K_{4,4}$ only has $8$ vertices!

(In general, for large $n$, $K_{n,n}$ only has a subdivision of $K_t$ for $t = O(\sqrt n)$ for the same reason.)

Comment: Thanks a ton! This was really interesting and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

$K_{2,2,2}$ is also an elegant example. It would need to contain a subdivision of $K_5$. The trivial subdivision ($K_5$ itself) is clearly not a subgraph, and there's only one subdivision with 6 vertices. The easiest way to note that this subdivision isn't in $K_{2,2,2}$ is to note that $K_{2,2,2}$ has a 1-factor as its complement, whereas the subdivision of $K_5$ does not.